# what are the best tools / addons to build html5 websites

Tags: visual-studio, html

i am trying to figure out the best environment for building html5 websites.  i have an existing asp.net-mvc site so i have been using visual studio.

What are the main features in visual studio to help you build html5 websites.  Are there any particular plugins or addons that you need to install that are essential to use or are there other environments / tools that should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://html5boilerplate.com/ I'm not sure if this is what your looking for, but it could be a start